# Why Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) give me an error on install?

Tags: android, eclipse, bios

I have install the Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) from SDK tools (I needed to enhanced the AVD Android virtual device on my eclipse) and then I lunched the exe file to install on my device so I get an error telling me that

```
the computer meets the requirements but Intel Virtualization Technology VT-x is not turned on. Please turned the VT-x on and then reinstall HAXM.
```

I searched about this and I found that I should change a BIOS setting for Intel from disabled to enabled:

```
Virtualization Technology  <Enabled>
```

I have HP laptop I went to the BIOS and change this and save start (windows 8) again and reinstall the HAXM but same error shown again.
Should I do something else to make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8. Android Studio.
Make sure if virtualization is enable : please go through the steps provided below.

> Goto setting -> change pc settings-> general->then see on right side
>   by scrolling the frame down-> you will see under advance start up
>   restart now button press it->then choose an option window will
>   open->choose troubleshoot->under troubleshoot choose Advance
>   option->then under Advance options choose UEFI Firmware option->then
>   press restart->press f10 for BIOS->see the menubar where you will find
>   system configuration menu inside it you will see the virtualization
>   Technology "enable" it ->now go for exit saving changes in exit on
>   menu bar..

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

(in username : please enter valid user name)

install it and restart your Android Studio.

if you make few changes on above process, they are same for win 7 or above and also same for eclipse have fun!!

Comment: Switch this from code to text please, this is just awful to read. I'll switch my down vote when you fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have installed Hyper-V, that makes running other VTx applications harder. 
But I doubt that's the case.

Try running HWINFO32/64 and see if the VTx flag is detected.

Comment: If VTx is indeed greyed out, then it means it is not enabled in the bios, even though you did enable something there. Maybe there is another option in the bios? Check your motherboard manual or google for vtx and your motherboard name.

Comment: Actually Hyper-V cannot run side by side with HAXM in any capacity, it's one or the other. If you want to switch between them, it requires you to turn one off, restart your machine and turn the other one on. Reference here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some cases with HP, where restarting didn't help. We needed to power off the PC or event take out the battery from a notebook. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case here!

Comment: Nice. Please let me know if this helps.